# Replace a certain value with another

Tags: r

I have this `x.Rdata` file which stores the variable `x` (11519 entries).
The data set looks like this:

```
[1] 8120 8120 4110 8120 4430 4310 8140 4120 8130 8140 1232 4430 8220 8120 3210 1110 8130 8140 

[19]4110 8210 2140 4310 7120 4120 8140 8110 1110 3210 6240 4310 3210 2140 8210 1232 8120 8120 

[37]4310 4430 4120 4120 1231 8110 8140 4120 4110 1110 8220 7120 8120 4110 1110 6230 4120 4120 

[55]8130 8120 8220 1110 1110 4110 4120 8140 8130 4210 4210 4110 6240 1232 1232 1232 4120 4120 

.......
```

I want to replace every entry of the value 1110 with 1310.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good candidate for `sapply`:

`x <- sapply(x, function(y) { if (y == 1110) 1310 else y })`

`sapply` applies a function to every entry in a vector and returns a new vector containing the result.

More information: [Apply a Function over a List or Vector](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/lapply.html).

Comment: Isn't this just `x[x == 1110] <- 1310` ? (didn't downvote btw)